# Pass values of dynamic text boxes to an existing hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to explain in a simple way something that totally has me stumped.  I have been working on this for over 9 hours now and ready to pull out my hair.

I have a form, with an existing hidden element and a number of text boxes.

Each text box as a blur event that creates inner.html of a certain div, which adds a number of text boxes based on the value entered (see image for clarification.

The code used to generate the textboxes is as follows:

```
function generate6(count) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ch.innerHTML = ch.innerHTML + "Left Text (size 6):  <
      input type = 'text'
    class = 'txt'
    style = 'width:150px;margin-right:10px;'
    name = 'left' + i > ";

    ch.innerHTML = ch.innerHTML + "Right Text (size 6): <input type='text' 
    class = 'txt'
    style = 'width:150px;margin-right:0px;'
    name = 'right' + i > < br > ";
  }
}

function generate7(count) {
  var j;
  for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    ch7.innerHTML = ch7.innerHTML + "Left Text (size 7): <input type='text'
    class = 'txt'
    style = 'width:150px;margin-right:10px;'
    name = 'left' + j > ";
    ch7.innerHTML = ch7.innerHTML + "Right Text (size 7): <input type='text' 
    class = 'txt'
    style = 'width:150px;margin-right:0px;'
    name = 'right' + j > < br > ";
  }
}
```

This repeats for all sizes, up to size 14.

I also have a hidden field on the form near the add to cart button.  I need to pass the VALUES of ALL of the dynamic text boxes into that hidden field before submitting the form.

At this point, I don't care how it works, just that it does.  Please help me.[image]

Comment: How should the values of multiple inputs be put into the hidden field? Space-separated?

Comment: Bug: you're using the names left1 - n and right1 - n for every size.  You should be using left7_1, left7_2, left11_1, etc.

Comment: At this point I don't even care.  One big blob will work fine - haha.  I can fix it later.  But nothing is working.

Comment: Oh, and I was going to try and ignore the names, and just grab all dynamic input text and throw it in the hidden field.  I have tried everything - I don't understand why nothing is working.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what problem you are having. The question talks about a blur event and a hidden form field but the code seems to relate to the dynamic construction of the text fields. Where is your attempted submit handler?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Attach an event handler for the `submit` event to the form
- Fetch all the inputs in the event handler
- Collect the values of all those inputs
- Update the hidden input with those values

html

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="hidden" name="dynamicInputsCollector">
  <input id="dynamicInput1">
  <input id="dynamicInput2">
  <!-- etc.... -->
</form>
```

js (example with jQuery):

```
var $form = $('#form');
var $dynamicInputCollector = $('#dynamicInputsCollector');

//Attach event handler for 'submit' event
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
  var $dynamicInputs = $("#form :input");
  var allDynamicInputs;
  $dynamicInputs.each(function(dynamicInput) {
    //Concatenate all dynamicInpus into one string (with '-' here as an example)
    allDynamicInputs = allDynamicInputs + '-' + $(dynamicInput).val()
  });
  //Update the hidden field
  $dynamicInputCollector.val(allDynamicInputs);
});
```

Comment: I love this and so wanted it to work - but when I added it, it simply left the hidden field blank when the form submitted.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I feel like this is so close.  I just can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Can you run some tests?
In the event handler: 
console.log('here');
console.log($dynamicInputs);
console.log(allDynamicInputs);

Comment: Nothing shows up.  I don't give up easily.  But honestly, this one has me completely baffled.  I can't sleep until it is working.  I hate being a programmer sometimes.

Comment: if nothing shows up it means that the event handler is not triggered.
Make sure your form has the correct id ($form should not be empty), and make sure you have a submit input in the form (<input type="submit">)

Comment: If I manually add a value to the hidden field it works.  If I submit the form to a test page, all dynamic fields show up fine.

Comment: Object expected:  var $form = $('#missbond');

Comment: does the $form object points to the form? (console.log($form));

Comment: Why `$("#form :input");`, not `$("#form input");` or `$form.find("input");`?

Comment: Actually changed it to $("#form input"); which did not work.  And yes, the console does point to the form.